# check if all input tags have value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to perform some action if all the input fields have some some value. So I am checking wether the input field have value using length condition but its not working correctly

```js
if($(".form-control:empty").length == 0){
            console.log('All are filled')
          
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="instance-dir"  placeholder="Instance Directory"  class="form-control"/>
<input type="text" id="Wroking-dir"  placeholder="Working directory"  class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Next time please add the correct tags to your question. Seems like you are using jquery and not vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`:empty` pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) checks for *child nodes*, it doesn't check for values. `input` elements never have child nodes (they're void elements).

CSS doesn't have a "`input` with no value" selector, and looking at [jQuery's list](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I don't see one that it adds. So you'll have to look through the elements, for instance:

```
if ($(".form-control").get().every(e => e.value))) {
    // Every `.form-control` has a non-blank value
}
```

Comment: some input will have value as undefined this case will be handled right?How can I check if value is not empty and undefined also

Comment: input value should not be empty andshould not have undefined as value

Comment: @shee8 - By definition, an `input` element's `value` property is never `undefined`. It's always a string. But if it *could* be `undefined`, the check above would check for those too, because both `""` and `undefined` are *falsy* values, and the above checks to see that every `input` has a *truthy* value.

Comment: @shee8 - No, it doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/fr1qucns/ There must be an error in your test. (And again: The `value` of an `input` element is never `undefined`. Do you have non-`input`/`select` elements with `.form-control`?)

Comment: If I have a folder icon within input tag and if I browse within my local machine to select a folder and if I dont select one and click cancel instead of ok the value of input field is undefined

Comment: @shee8 - No. It. Isn't. For the third time: If it's an [`input`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement) field, `value` cannot be undefined. If you continue to cling to the idea that somehow that's not true, you're going to continue to overlook the *real* problem.

Comment: okay .Just how can I check if value is undefined or not?

Comment: @shee8 `someVariableOrProperty === undefined` or `typeof someVariableOrProperty === "undefined"` (note quotes on the second one, and **no** quotes on the first one).

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs have the `required` tag then you can use `input:valid` to check if its been filled out.

```js
$('#check').on('click', function() {
  if (!$('input[type="text"]:not(:valid)').length) console.log('All are filled');
  else console.log('Some are missing');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="instance-dir" placeholder="Instance Directory" class="form-control" required />
<input type="text" id="Wroking-dir" placeholder="Working directory" class="form-control" required/>

<button id="check">Check</button>
```